# Serial conection HMT310

Tags: usb, serial, ttl

How to connect the HMT310 via serial port? When I connect it and open PuTTY and put "?" for it to show me the data, it pulls all "U"s. I already checked that the baudrate and other parameters are fine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a USB to TTL adapter, not USB to RS-232 adapter.

The sensor speaks RS-232, not TTL.

You need to convert between TTL and RS-232, or you could just have direct USB to RS-232, or the PC might have a RS-232 port already.